# AndroidJavaObject.Call GetCurrentPosition

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get current position of a video player, but I don't know how to take this int to another variable, (a int).

I dont know if I done right i'm using C# and unity.

I'm Using `AndroidJavaObject.Call` to do that.

```
int currentPos;
void Update()
{
    #if (UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR)
    mediaPlayer.Call("getCurrentPosition", currentPos);

    if(currentPos > 3000)
    {
        mediaPlayer.Call("seekTo", 0);
    }
    #endif
}
```

Nothing happens,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Unity documentation:

> To call a Java method with a non-void return type, use the generic
>   version.

So it is:

```
currentPos = mediaPlayer.Call<int>("getCurrentPosition");
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.Call.html